# How do i Push or pull to bitbucket from my remote machine which has no internet

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, remote-access, remote-desktop

I am logged in to a remote machine from my desktop. All my automation scripts and the application is on the remote machine.

Now we are setting up a version control system using bitbucket which we can access it from my computer but not from the remote as there is no internet connection on the remote machine?

How do you guys suggest me going through this?

I've tried creating a remote repository but that still needs a connection to the internet.

Do i need to ssh or use some kind of proxy.

Any pointers to how to set that up would be appreciated.

Comment: If the remote machine has network, but it can’t surf the internet. That means you may still connect to bitbucket repo in git bash by `git clone <URL for bitbucket repo>`.

Comment: Would this clone my bitbucket repo to my local on the remote machine?. Tried it but it wasn't able to connect to the  link and it timed out.

Comment: So you can't clone bitbucket repo from remote machine? I give an answer to connect remote machine with local, and local machine with bitbucket. But you need to install SSH server on remote machine at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by cloning the bitbucket repo to my local machine. And then mapping my local drivers to my remote desktop.

Any code changes that we make on the remote desktop, we make it by accessing our mapped drive. 
Once the changes have been done, we commit and push it from our local machine to bitbucket server.

Answer (score 1):

How can you be logged into a remote machine if is not connected to a network ?.. Is a local Network?

I used ssh to connect and command remote machines and worked pretty nicely... but this needs networking of the machines as well.

Comment: Ofcourse the machine is connected to a network. its just not connected to the internet. may be they've blocked it. What i am after is, is there a way i can access the internet on my machine from the remote?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a bare repo in local machine, this will work as remote repo for your remote machine.

1.Before that, you need to **install SSH server on your remote machine**. Detail setup steps you can refer [OpenSSH server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server).

2.Then **create a bare repo in local machine and add remote for local bitbucket repo**:

```
# in an empty folder, such as C:\Users\username\bare
git init --bare
# in a different folder
git clone <URL for bitbucket repo>
cd reponame
git remote add bare C:/Users/username/bare
git push bare master
```

3.**Clone bare repo from local machine to remote machine**:

```
git clone git+ssh://username@<IP address>/~/bare
cd bare
# make changes
git add .
git commit 
git push
```

While, `username` is the username for remote machine, `IP address` is remote machine IP.

Now you can pushed changes from remote machine to local machine.

4.Finally **push change from local machine to bitbucket**:

```
# in bitbucket local copy in local machine
git pull bare master --rebase
git push origin master
```